# How to 'LOCK' a Linqpad script with a Linqpad Connection - so that the Linqpad script will work with only one connection

Tags: connection, linqpad

How to 'LOCK' a Linqpad script with a Linqpad Connection - so that the Linqpad script will work with only one connection.

When I run a Linqpad script - I would like to make sure that only 1 connection will work

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking to a sql database, then you could throw an exception if the Connection.Database or Connection.DataSource  is not what you expect.

eg

```
   if (!(this.Connection.Database  .Equals(database , StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) || 
       !(this.Connection.DataSource.Equals(sqlServer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
           throw new Exception(String.Format("This script only applies to database {0} on {1}", database , sqlServer));
```

If you are linking to something other than sql, then you may need to do check `this.Connection.ConnectionString` is what you expect.